# How to show typed in text as individual div's in a textarea

Tags: jquery, html

When I append multiple div and there one textarea, when I Enter text in textarea then text show individual div.

When I type "demo" show demo in one div, then another text enter in textarea like "Example" show second div.

**Html**

```
<textarea class="speechttxt" rows="3" cols="4" style="height: 75px;width: 267px; background: inherit; border: 1px solid #999; white-space: pre-wrap; resize: none; margin-bottom: 6px; padding-right: 0;"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
var speech = '<div id="speechID" class="SpeechBubble"><div  class="txtspeech" id="lbl' + (c++) + '"></div></div>';
$('#video_container').append(speech);
$('.speechttxt').keyup(function () {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  $('.txtspeech').html(txt);
});
```

Its working, but when I append second div then text enter in textarea show in second div.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: Are you creating a chat like system?

Answer (score 1):

The second div changes because both divs have the `txtspeech` class, so this line `$('.txtspeech').html(txt)` targets both divs.

It's not clear in the sample when are you creating the second div.